# Cached version by Google of my website shows the Google Custom Search window open (with No Results)

Tags: google-custom-search

I am using Google Custom Search on my website for a quite a while. I have noticed that when I open the Google-cached version of my website, it shows the Custom Search result window open (saying No Results) for no reason.

You can see for yourself here:

https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:z55mQx1mHn8J:https://www.fireplace.co.uk/+&cd=122&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk

Here is a screenshot:

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMw8I.png

I havent been able to find ANYTHING about this issue on Google and I havent gotten a single reply on the Google Custom Search support forum for more than a week.

Does anyone please have any idea what could be causing this and how to resolve it? It is really annoying to see the cached version of my website covered by a modal window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this question while looking for something and, although it's been a while since it was asked, I noticed the problem is not solved so thought I'd try to help.

By looking at the cache URL you've provided, the reason you see the modal window seems to be the fact that the same URL variable (q=...) is being used by both, the webcache page AND by the Google custom search on your website.

So, when someone opens the cached page, the custom search engine is also being fired because of the presence of the q URL variable.

In the case of the cached page, the search term (value of q variable) is "cache:z55mQx1mHn8J:https://www.fireplace.co.uk/+&cd=122&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk" and if you paste this value in the actual search on fireplace.co.uk you'll see that it returns an empty search results window.

The solution would probably be to update your custom search engine so that it uses a different variable than the default one (which is q). That can be done, just look in the custom search documentation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I believe you are correct, I have changed the queryParameterName attribute in the <gse> tag and that should hopefully sort it out. Thank you for taking your time to reply, even though its an old question.